# accessing NSDictionary property of class in init function gives error "use of undeclared identifier". Need help understanding why

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is a class for a deck of cards that could have several different configurations that I define using a NSDictionary with string keys and array values of how the cards are to be added.  I haven't completed the init function yet, but it gives me the error above on trying to access my NSDictionary property.  Fairly new to objective-c sorry if this is trivial question.

Here is my .m class file:

```
@interface MarioCardDeck()

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSDictionary *cardConfigurations;

@end


@implementation MarioCardDeck

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        unsigned index = arc4random() % [[cardConfigurations allKeys] count]; ** error line

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)cardConfigurations
{
    if(!_cardConfigurations)
    {
        _cardConfigurations = @{
                                @"1" :
                                    @[@"flower",@"coin20",@"mushroom",@"star",@"oneUp",@"flower",@"oneUp",@"flower",@"coin10",@"mushroom",@"coin20",@"star",@"mushroom",@"coin10",@"star",@"mushroom",@"flower",@"star"],
                                @"2" :
                                    @[@"flower",@"coin10",@"oneUp",@"flower",@"oneUp",@"mushroom",@"star",@"mushroom",@"coin20",@"star",@"mushroom",@"coin10",@"star",@"flower",@"coin20",@"mushroom",@"flower",@"star"]
                                };

    }
    return _cardConfigurations;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
unsigned index = arc4random() % [[self.cardConfigurations allKeys] count];
```

You need to access the property by using `self`.

FYI - you should use:

```
unsigned index = arc4random_uniform([[self.cardConfigurations allKeys] count]);
```

Comment: Is there a way to have self implied?  I just started learning and I think I read somewhere about `@synthesize` allowing you to not have to explicitly declare self?  but it still doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: `@synthesize` and using `self` have nothing to do with each other. `self` is used to reference anything in the same instance as the caller whether it be a property or an instance method. You can't get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to it by `self.cardConfigurations`.

Comment: The property is lazy loaded so using the ivar directly in any case is a bad idea.

Comment: Messaging `self` in an `init` is also not the best idea.

Comment: Agreed but it only becomes a potential issue if a subclass overrides the property's getter.

Comment: do you think it would be better to just make cardConfigurations a class method?

Comment: If the dictionary never changes you would save some memory by making it a class method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
unsigned index = arc4random() % [[cardConfigurations allKeys] count];
```

to

```
unsigned index = arc4random() % [[self.cardConfigurations allKeys] count];
```

Accessing properties in the init method is, however, dangerous thing to do in Objective-C. If the getter is overridden in a subclass you might get a nasty surprise. I would make another property for the index, assign the instance variable to NSNotFound, and do the calculation the first the time the getter method is called. Also, you should use NSUInteger as the type for storing the index.